# Java appletviewer

Tags: java, applet, package, classnotfoundexception, appletviewer

I wrote a simply Hello World java applet and called it `HelloApplet.java`.  I created an html file for it called HelloApplet.html.  Both files along with the compiled `HelloApplet.class` file all reside on my Windows 7 computer's `C:\temp` directory.  The `HelloApplet.html` files has two lines:

```
<applet codes = "HelloApplet" width = 300 height = 300>
</applet>
```

From the `C:\temp` directory I execute

```
appletviewer HelloApplet.html
```

and everything works just as expected.

I run into a problem when I add a package statement to the top of my java code.  The first line reads:

```
package applet;
```

I then change the html file's first line to read:

```
<applet code = "applet.HelloApplet" width = 300 height = 300>
```

Still from `C:\temp` I run `appletviewer` but this time it doesn't work.  The class file can't be found.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My HelloApplet.html is shown below:

Answer (score 4):

In Java, When you refactor your code and move your class to a package, you have to move the corresponding file (HelloApplet.java) into a sub-folder named after your package. That means your folder hierarchy should match the packaging scheme you've chosen for your application. This way, if your class is on a package named `a.b.c`, then your class should be on a `{source folder}\a\b\c` folder.

In your example, you have to make a new folder called `applet` in your `c:\temp5` folder and move your class into it, then compile and run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `code` attribute according to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html)

```
<applet code = "applet.HelloApplet.class" width = 300 height = 300>
```

and move the file `HelloApplet.class` to the `applet` folder.

Comment: That is *incorrect*.  The `code` attribute should be the Fully Qualified Name of the class, using `.`.  So `applet.HelloApplet` (as the OP currently has it) is *correct*.

Comment: ***No!***  If I'd meant that `applet.HelloApplet.class` was correct I'd have said that.  It is not, the FQN is **`applet.HelloApplet`**.  No more, no less.  That longer forms is 'tolerated', and repeated ad nauseam throughout the tutorial, but not correct.

Answer (score 0):

As moghaddam said, when you specify a package in a Java applet/application you need to reflect the package in the directory hierarchy. Thus, if you have an `applet` package, the directory tree should be (in your case)

```
C:\
└── temp
    └── applet
        └── HelloApplet.class
```

and from temp you should be able to execute `appletviewer applet.HelloApplet`